# ggplot error inside code chunks but not in console: Warning in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open compressed file?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

Well folks, I'm stumped.

I have a .Rmd file within a RStudio project. In one of the code chunks I am using dplyr functions to summarize a data frame and then plot a histogram of the summarized data with ggplot2. When I run the ggplot code, I get this very ugly error message:

```r
Warning in gzfile(file, "wb") :
  cannot open compressed file '/Users/ebar/Dropbox/R/NoCoWildDataProcessing/.Rproj.user/shared/notebooks/53CC2A92-Explain-Flattenning-data /1/4FF2C393C9CC962A/cmine11fvbhpf_t/fac421ffa1b249f19ac853590bff56e8.snapshot', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
Error in (function (which = dev.cur())  : 
  QuartzBitmap_Output - unable to open file '/Users/ebar/Dropbox/R/NoCoWildDataProcessing/.Rproj.user/shared/notebooks/53CC2A92-Explain-Flattenning-data /1/4FF2C393C9CC962A/cmine11fvbhpf_t/_rs_chunk_plot_001.png'
```

The code block in the `.Rmd` includes only the following:

```r
data_summary<-data %>% group_by(subject_ids) %>% summarise(
  NumClassifications = length(unique(classification_id))
) 

ggplot(data_summary, aes(NumClassifications))+
  geom_histogram()
```

When I copy the ggplot code to the console and run it there, the histogram appears in the plot window just fine and I get no error message. I'd really like to be able to keep it all contained in the code block. I've done so in many other cases and have never run into this problem.

I have tried the following steps to see if they could help:

1. Searching this issue on SO and reading through the similar questions
2. Restarting the R session
3. Quitting and restarting RStudio
4. Updating R and all of my packages
5. Deleting the .Rproj.user file from my project folder

None of it has helped.

The project is housed in a Dropbox folder, and it is not a shared project. I have dozens and dozens of other R projects on Dropbox and have never seen this issue.  My local disk also has plenty of space.

Here are some sample data (I get the error when I use these sample data as well as the full dataset):

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~subject_ids, ~NumClassifications,
     52256341L,                  1L,
     52256564L,                  1L,
     52256696L,                  1L,
     52259301L,                  1L,
     52259303L,                  1L
  )
```

And here is the sessionInfo

```
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] knitr_1.33        magrittr_2.0.1    rlang_0.4.11      fansi_0.4.2      
#>  [5] stringr_1.4.0     styler_1.4.1      highr_0.9         tools_4.0.5      
#>  [9] xfun_0.22         utf8_1.2.1        withr_2.4.2       htmltools_0.5.1.1
#> [13] ellipsis_0.3.2    yaml_2.2.1        digest_0.6.27     tibble_3.1.1     
#> [17] lifecycle_1.0.0   crayon_1.4.1      purrr_0.3.4       vctrs_0.3.8      
#> [21] fs_1.5.0          glue_1.4.2        evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_2.7    
#> [25] reprex_2.0.0      stringi_1.5.3     compiler_4.0.5    pillar_1.6.0     
#> [29] backports_1.2.1   pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

I would greatly appreciate any pointers!

Comment: There appears to be a space in the path. R does have trouble with spaces on Windows, perhaps that problem exists on other OSes as well in situations like this. Additionally, that looks like it's being rendered (not just *saved*) within a Dropbox directory/share, which could also be a problem. Try changing *where* the file is being rendered, perhaps in a temp-dir, having the results saved to the dropbox dir if need be.

Comment: (More the point about the Dropbox share: R has trouble in other areas when compiling or packaging or other things when the directory is something like a network share. I don't have experience testing it on Dropbox, but almost all of those issues are resolved when the "hard part" is done on a completely local directory, not in dropbox or NFS or CIFS or anything like that.)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I don't know how to control where the plot is being rendered.  Would it work to save the .Rmd locally and run it locally?

Comment: And I see what you mean about the space in the file path - which is confusing. I would have thought that R would create a file path that it liked (I didn't designate the file path).

Comment: Do you have a section or chapter or code-chunk named `"Explain-Flattenning-data "`? If there's an inferred space in that title, perhaps that's part of the problem. It might be that the name is even longer, in which case it is being truncated for a unique name, and its uniquification is ... perhaps flawed. Just thoughts.

Comment: As far as "where", if you're using `rmarkdown::render` then look into the arguments `intermediates_dir` vs `output_dir`.

Comment: OH MY GOSH @r2evans you are my HERO! I've been staring at this for a few hours now, researching, etc., and never saw the space in front of the .Rmd in my file name!!!! Thank you thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: (I think it's still a bug, mind you, but at least it's an avoidable bug.)

Answer (score 2):

So the problem was that I had an unintended space in the name of my `.Rmd` file that I just didn't see (the space was right before the `.`. The moral of the story: more eyes on your code are better, and it is lucky to have such a great community of folks on SO willing to help each other out!